# Invalid API message when Lumen application access in web

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

The below scripts works in web and api, but I have other endpoint for login it works fine with postman.

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return 'The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request.';
});
```

If I access `http://lumen.api.local/api/v2/login` url in web its showing

```
{
  "message": "Method not allowed."
}
```

Instead of this I want to show custom message here.
Could you please help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you show your `api.php` routes file. Also, are you just wanting to override the default message for the `MethodNotAllowedException`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to configure it on your middlewear,in my case
I have it on /blog/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

You only have to search in your files for the message and change it.